# how to find Wordpress theme homepage file source code

Tags: wordpress

my website using wordpress template and I want to edit the homepage but I can't find the source file of the homepage...i go to chrome - view source but can't find the index.php that has the source code of the homepage

how to find the file of the source code of the homepage

Comment: 1) Learn how to use a child theme.  Takes 15 minutes to learn, saves you hours.  2) Learn how the template hierarchy works.  3) Remember that a whole lot of content is contained within posts and pages within a WordPress site.  (that means the content is in the database, not in a particular template page).  Good luck with this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

its depending on the file used by author.  by the way, most of the themes have, home.php

front-page.php

index.php

otherwise, we can create a custom page in wp-admin and assign it as home page or front page to a wordpress, that will be configured on the settings page.

Go through it.

Answer (score -1):

Start here https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development to learn how WordPress themes are designed and coded.